# Is there any reason to chose ES, FS, or GS over the others in real mode?

Tags: memory, intel

The [Wikipedia page on *X86 Memory Segmentation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_segmentation) says

> In real mode, the registers `CS`, `DS`, `SS`, and `ES` point to the currently used program code segment (`CS`), the current data segment (`DS`), the current stack segment (`SS`), and one extra segment determined by the programmer (`ES`). The Intel 80386, introduced in 1985, adds two additional segment registers, `FS` and `GS`, with no specific uses defined by the hardware.

Was there any technical or social reason to chose `FS`/`GS`/`ES`? Was there a convention with regard to any of these?

Comment: ES has some specific uses defined by hardware, with the MOVS instruction for example. FS/GS were almost never used in 16-bit code, even by code that required other '386 features.  They were (and are) used in 32-bit code for certain fixed purposes by DOS extenders and operating systems. (eg. FS as a thread local pointer in Windows and Linux).

Comment: You could, maybe, see these registers as a bit exotic, which was basically caused by the operating systems of the time: "Standard" DOS applications couldn't use them, as they would have lost compatibility with earlier CPUs, and new, 386-only systems tended to use linear 32bit addressing, thus not having a lot of use for segment registers, so they were pretty much ignored by standard applications and compilers for a long time.

Answer (score 11):

TL;DR: **No**.

---

By default all memory addresses are within DS. Exceptions are the destination addresses of STOSx/MOVSx and CMPSx where ES is used (*1). DS can be replaced by any other segment register in all instructions by adding a segment override prefix.

So with the exception of ES when it comes to string destination segment any segment can be used (overwritten) at cost of an additional instruction byte. Which segment register to be used when leaving the default is rather arbitrary.

The introduction of FS/GS eased the need to reload segment registers.

Adding one segment (FS) eased A=B+C type operations where each of the components resides in a separate segment, like when doing large amounts of data (tables), without constant reloading of segment registers. After all, each load needs not only to load all segment information, but also runs necessary privilege checks. It still requires reloading of DS after such sections.

Adding a two (FS&GS) even removed that restriction, allowing a program to hold three arbitrary data segments in addition to Code, Programm Data and Stack.

**Fire at Will**

---

*1 - And then there are all addressing modes with BP and SP,as they are calculated with SS as base value - after all, BP is the stack frame pointer.

Comment: IMHO, the original 8086 segmentation design was brilliant, save for the lack of a few instructions like `mov segreg,immed` and second "scratchpad" segment register.  The 80286 is my least favorite design, because it massively increased the cost of repeated segment-register loads without doing anything to alleviate the need for them.  The wimpy 16-bit selectors make 80386 segmentation just about useless, but fortunately the large offsets minimize the need for it.

Comment: The 286 competes the 16 bit design as it now offers large and virtual memory while being fully compatible. Any clean 8086 code (that is none using atrocities like huge memory model / calculated segment values) culd run right away in a virtual memory environment. Sure, the implementation how segment descriptors are haldled was less than great. Still, increased speeds did more than compensate for this. Ofc, code written against the segmentation philosopy did not realy do well. Not Intels fault.

Comment: The 286 design has two major flaws: (1) Loading segment registers is far more expensive than on the 8086.  On the 8086, a loop to compute a[i]=b[i]+c[i] with the three values in different segments could cache two of the segments in BX and DX, minimizing the time to reload them, but on the 80286, each `mov ds,bx` would require reloading a segment descriptor.  (2) Segments are too expensive to grant one to each allocation, but it's difficult to consolidate free space that is shared between segments; such inability to do so can make it hard to avoid excessive memory fragmentation.

Comment: If segments were cheap enough that an object-based language could simply use segment descriptors as object IDs (treat every object as starting at offset zero of some segment), that could have facilitated a really nice design, especially if there were a means of having multiple selector values share a descriptor (e.g. use the upper bits of the selector to choose a descriptor, and the lower bits as a sub-index which would be scaled and added to the offset).  Unfortunately, segment selectors are too short to make that useful.

Comment: @supercat For one, there's sill ES, so only one descriptor gets to be trashed per operation, but that's not the point, as it's a worst case assumption. With well written code a 286 delivers considerable higehr performance than a 8086 due the higher clock speed. But that's not the point, as it's true feature is the availibility of more memory and virtual addressing to run concurent tasks. Ofc, all of this can be nullified by code that reloads segment registers on next to every variable - that's already stupid on a plain 8086. And, as usual, wishing for a different CPU won't change rality.

Comment: The only way to avoid frequent segment register loads is to arrange related objects into common segments.  That can improve things a lot if one is using machine code, but high-level languages don't support that except for one main data segment, the stack segment, and for Turbo Pascal versions before 4.0, the code segment.  I know Intel CPUs are what they are, but it's ironic that Intel added FS: and GS: to an architecture where they were no longer really needed.

Comment: In 16-bit real mode SP can't be used as part of an effective address, only BP. On a 386 it is possible (in real mode) to use ESP as part of an effective address.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Wait, you mean, one can't do push and pop in real mode?

Comment: @Raffzahn : It says `addressing modes with BP and SP,` . There are no `addressing modes` where _SP_ is allowed as a base address. Push and Pop are always implicit but they are not considered `addressing modes`

Comment: @MichaelPetch _'not considered' is a rather individual view, isn't it? push and pop uses, as you say, an implicit addressing. Isn't it? so where's the issue?

Comment: I'm actually using the definitions from the Intel manuals. Not including segment overrides there are a combination of 17 valid memory addressing modes (with 16-bit addressing in real mode not including segment overrides). Real mode on a 386 of course can support all the 32-bit addressing modes through an operand size prefix in real mode.

Comment: @MichaelKarcher Naa, cool, in fact, when rereading, I didn't see that part at all. Guess that why one always needs someone else to proofread. I did add '(overwrite)' as well to make it more clear. Ok?  Don't forget to clean up comments